# Error uploading images in php

Tags: php, mysql, image-upload

My code is echoing else statement when i upload jpg file. Am i missing something where am i going wrong?

Its on line 39 of the code btw

```
if(($type=="image/jpeg") || ($type=="image/JPG") || ($type=="image/bmp") || ($type=="image/png")) 
{
    move_uploaded_file($temp, "images/$mypic");
    echo "What a pretty face! <img border='1' width='50' height='50' src='images/$mypic'><p>";
    mysqli_query($link,$query);

    echo ("user registered successfully!<a href='home.php'>Login now!</a>");
}
else
{
    echo ($type);
    echo "Please load a valid jpeg, jpg or bmp! And size must be less than 10k!";           }
}
```

Comment: Its on line 39...Its hard to realise we don't know which is the line 39?

Comment: result of `echo $type;`?

Comment: Do you mean your code execute the else statement when you upload jpg file ?

Comment: use this `$type=str2lower($type);` before condition and use small caps letters

Comment: @imsiso has the correct idea, it may not be getting the extension correctly.

Comment: *"Its on line 39 of the code btw"* - There's like... `13` lines here. * Cough * - Show us your FULL code. I'll bet it has something to with something OUTSIDE that shown-code, or it's a DB issue.

Answer (score 0):

try doing like:

```
$type_arr = array(
  "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/bmp", "image/png"
);
//and
$type = strtolower($type);
if( in_array($type, $type_arr) ) {
    //your upload code here
}
else {
   //error message
   echo $type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your file size problem.check it once.

```
$allow = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");

$todir = 'uploads/';

if ( !!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) // is the file uploaded yet?
{
$ext = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['file']['name']) ); // whats the extension of the file

if ( in_array( $ext, $allow) ) // is this file allowed
{
    if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $todir . basename($_FILES['file']['name'] ) ) )
    {
        // the file has been moved correctly
    }
}
else
{
    // error this file ext is not allowed
}
}
```

Comment: not a good code why not using mime types? instead of extensions?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are checking for an image , i wil just do this

```
if(!(getimagesize ($temp)==0))
{
//an image
}
else
{
//not an image
}
```